# "BIP1936E: Authentication failure" connecting to secured Integration Node with mqsideploy

Tags: deployment, ant, ibm-integration-bus

```xml
<target name="deployBar" description="deploys a bar file">
    <echo message="Executing mqsideploy -n '${broker}' -e '${integrationServer}' -a '${servicename}-${version}-${environment}.bar'"/>
    <exec executable="${mqsideploy.path}" inputstring="abcd" failonerror="false">
        <arg value="-n" />
        <arg value="${broker}" />
        <arg value="-e" />
        <arg value="${integrationServer}" />
        <arg value="-a" />
        <arg value="${servicename}-${version}-${environment}.bar" />
        <arg value="-w" />
        <arg value="2145336164" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

I am trying to use the above Ant script on my Windows machine to compile a message broker application, create a deployable BAR file and finally deploy it to a secured Integration node. The Integration node is secured by digital certificates by a userid/password.

I am stuck passing the password to the deployment command and the command fail with message "BIP1936E: Authentication failure when connecting to the secured remote integration node 'localhost:4415'. Please specify a valid userid and password."

I have verified the password by manually executing the same command through command console. I am attaching the build.xml snippet that I tried out. Let me know, if the format of passing the password is correct i.e. `inputstring="abcd"`.